# Converting ros::Time to plain data structure

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`ros::time` is derived from Time and Time class has 2 members `uint32 sec, nsec`. If I have ros::time, how do I store it into plain structure where i just have 2 uint32 fields. `ros::time` has `toSec()` and `toNSec()`, but neither of which returns uint32.
How do I convert `ros::time` to

```
Message time {
  uint32 sec, nsec;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313670/converting-ros::time-to-plain-data-structure/) by [debonair](https://answers.ros.org/users/37218/debonair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`sec` and `nsec` are public members of the [ros::Time](http://docs.ros.org/latest/api/rostime/html/classros_1_1TimeBase.html) class:

```
  struct Time {
    uint32_t sec;
    uint32_t nsec;
  };

  Time t2;
  ros::Time t1;
  t2.sec = t1.sec;
  t2.nsec = t1.nsec;
```

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2019-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0